# Best approach for authentication method for native mobile apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, jwt

I'm pretty confused on what authentication method to use for my android/ios app.

I'm trying to create login for user and maintain session on the app. If token  based authentication is used for session, then it should have expiry time.

Shall I go ahead with [ApiAuth token based authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588781/rails-api-and-native-mobile-app-authentication) or [Json Web Token authentication](http://rohitrox.github.io/2015/06/23/so-you-want-to-create-an-awesome-rails-api-backed-with-jwt/) for my native apps. Please help me to choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, we have a substantially complex Rails API which is consumed by both iOS and Android client apps. We use JWT for authentication and it's working pretty well. There is a [jwt ruby gem](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt) as well. It's easy to have expiry time using JWT. This is also one of the most popular choices of it's kind, so I think you can definitely give this a shot.

Comment: I was not sure to use jwt for mobile apps. In some places I read that it is for single page applications and there is no clarity that it can be used for native mobile apps. Also I'm not if this is a best approach to use. Though, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: JWT is not only for single page application, that's for sure :)