# Create a Rails API for Deivse Authentication

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, devise

I've a rails app that uses devise authentication for users. Now I'm about to create an android app for the Rails application. Thus using rails-api https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api for developing the restful webservice. Now I've to write an custom session controller for authenticating the user via android app and generating the token for future auths with the scaffold models.

I'm using devise 3.4.1, in which the token authentication is removed.

Comment: The last answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623980/user-authentication-with-grape-and-devise) should be what you need.

Comment: You might also consider looking at [grape::wine_bouncer](https://github.com/antek-drzewiecki/wine_bouncer)

Comment: @AntarrByrd it was based on Devise 3.2, But I'm using Devise 3.4.1. Where the token authentication is removed