# How can I sign in user of devise in grape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape

I use Grape to implement an API service of my app. But how can I call devise method `sign_in` in Grape?

Comment: Please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623980/user-authentication-with-grape-and-devise

Comment: @rick , thanks. But I do not want to use token. And MY QUESTION IS how to auth user with username and password, which is before generating token.

Comment: @WildCat, You figured out how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In the Grape API base

```rb
# Enable session middleware for auth: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35428068/2771889
use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
helpers do
  def session
    env['rack.session']
  end
end
```

The API

```rb
helpers Devise::Controllers::SignInOut

resource :users do
  # ...
end
```

Note that this adds the Session layer to the API which will cause some overhead that Grape by default would avoid. For a full auth solution see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70683351/2771889

Answer (score -1):

You need to write API which will post user_name & password and return user toke in API response

As

http://localhost:3000/api/v0/auth/sign_up

POST parameter

```
user[email]=p@p.com
user[password]=p123
```

In AuthController

```
def sign_up
   #create user and user token 
   render json: { token: <generated user token>}  
end
```

You migth need to write similar api for sign_in as well 
Use this token for subsequent API call to authorize user

Comment: I mean that I want to use helpers of Devise instead of mine.