# Rails GrapeAPI + Authlogic undefined method `session'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic, grape-api

I'm trying to build an API for login using `GrapeAPI` and `Authlogic`.

My code looks like this:

```
class Api
  class V1
    class UserSessionsController < Grape::API


    post :login do
      @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
      if @user_session.save
        fetch_api_key(@user_session.user)
      else
        error!('Unauthorized.', 401)
      end
    end

    helpers do
      def current_user_session
        return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
        @current_user_session = UserSession.find
      end

      def current_user
        return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
        @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.user
       end

      end

    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that when I run `@user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])` I get `You must activate the Authlogic::Session::Base.controller with a controller object before creating objects`.

I tried adding

`Authlogic::Session::Base.controller = Authlogic::ControllerAdapters::RailsAdapter.new(self)`

before trying to create the `UserSession` and now I get `undefined method 'session' for #<#<Class:0x007fa7a63ade28>:0x007fa7a7b144b8>` when I run `@user_session.save`.

PS: I also tried adding `authenticate_with User` to the `user_session.rb` file, and

`acts_as_authentic do |c|
  c.session_class = UserSession
end`

Inside the `user` model, but it doesn't work.

PS2: I'm using rails 4,2,7 , grape 0.18.0 and authlogic 3.4.6

Comment: Have you looked at [the authentication section of grape's docs](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#authentication)? There's a section there on "Register custom middleware for authentication". Also, it might help to research [how people have integrated other authentication libraries, like devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623980/user-authentication-with-grape-and-devise).

Comment: Does your UserSession model inherit from Authligic, rather than ActiveRecord?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. 

@DanLaffan My model inherits from AuthLogic.

@JaredBeck I've looked at this, but I think the problem is in AuthLogic since the logic for rails apps is based on controllers which are subclasses of `ApplicationController` and with grape they are behaving differently.

Comment: Taking your point in reply to Jared, I wonder if AuthLogic would ever work for you?  Perhaps you could check out the RSpec/TestUnit support that AuthLogic offers.  Not sure if this idea would be of any real value to you though.