# Using a curl command to login to rails api with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, devise

I have a simple web app built with rails using devise for user log in. At the moment a user can sign up, sign in and sign out, and make new posts when signed in.
Eventually I plan to make this api consumable via a mobile app and my first step in understanding the process is to use a CURL command to log in. I am having some problems.

**Here is the CURL command:**

`curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in -d '{"user": {"email":"test@test.com", "password": "password"}}' -c cookie`

**Here is the controller code:**

```
class Api::PostsController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  # protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  def index
    render json: Post.all 
  end

  def show
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    render json: post
  end

  def create
    post = Post.new(post_params)
    if post.save
      render status: 200, json: {
        message: "Successfully created post",
        post: post
        }.to_json
    else
      render status: 422, json: {
        errors: post.errors
      }.to_json
    end
  end

  def destroy
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    post.destroy
    render status: 200, json: {
      message: 'Successfully deleted post'
    }.to_json
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require("post").permit("city", "country", "image", "lon", "lat")
  end

end
```

**Here is the error I am getting from the server:**

```
 Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "session"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 20ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

As you can see I've included the `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` code to skip the CSRF token check, however this check seems to be taking place in the `SessionsController`.

Do I need to add this line of code elsewhere? I am still new to Rails/Devise, so please forgive my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise is a Rails engine, so it has its own set of controllers which do not inherit from `ApplicationController`. To make the override work, you need to make controllers in your app that inherit from the devise ones, then tell Devise to use those instead of the default ones. [This](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers) how-to on the Devise wiki might help.

Having said that, the CSRF protection is there for a reason, and if you disable it, the users logging in via the web browser will no longer be protected, which is  a really bad idea. A better way to do this would be to have a proper mechanism for logging in via the API which is different from the web GUI. There is a [`:token_authenticatable`](https://github.com/baschtl/devise-token_authenticatable) module that will help here, and a good guide to using it [here](http://jessewolgamott.com/blog/2012/01/19/the-one-with-a-json-api-login-using-devise/).

However... the Platformatec guys who make Devise have removed `:token_authenticatable` from the core as they say it is not 100% secure (see [this blog post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/)). There is a good Stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605294/is-devises-token-authenticatable-secure) explaining the issues and suggesting some better ways to implement things.

Hope that throws some light on things.